# Modifying the_posts_pagination from within functions.php instead of template files

Tags: functions, pagination

I know that using a function like the following (in `functions.php`) allows me to customize pagination options:

```
function custom_theme_pagination(){
    global $wp_query; 
    echo paginate_links();
}
```

... provided that the theme file then contains `<?php custom_theme_pagination(); ?>` wherever I want the pagination to show.

However, what I would like to achieve is control how any instance of `<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>` will appear *without* having to create a custom function and then replacing the code in my theme files with `<?php custom_theme_pagination(); ?>` instead of `<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>`.

**Is it possible to modify or give arguments for the original `<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>` -- in the functions.php file, not in theme files -- without wrapping it in a custom function?** If yes, can you explain in detail how that works, please? I ask for details because I want to learn how to do this with pagination and be able to use what I learned for other similar matters that might come up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to modify or give arguments for the original  -- in the functions.php file, not in theme
>   files -- without wrapping it in a custom function?

No.

There are no hooks that allow modifying the arguments to this function. Wrapping it in your own function is the way to go. There's nothing inherently smarter or superior or more smarter about using filters.

Comment: So if I am working with a theme that already uses `the_posts_pagination` and want to customize the arguments, I would have to change all instances of that to my custom pagination function, correct?

Comment: Yes. That's right. Keeping in mind that you should be using a child theme if you intend to modify a theme.

Comment: And from your original answer, if I needed something to change a core function I would have to look and see if "hooks" exist? Otherwise, wrap what I need in a custom function, correct?

Comment: Right. The source for all functions is available at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/, which you can use to look. You're looking for `do_action()` and `apply_filters()`. Make sure to also check the functions that are used by other functions, as sometimes there's filters deeper down.

Comment: Great, thank you for the link :) I think I was looking at the wrong documentation or an old one.